# Ubuntu/Debian server loses network sporadically when wired and running Docker

Tags: debian, ubuntu, networking, docker

I have spent months on this problem, and I'm just about at my wits' end. I have a home media server that runs docker to run containers. I have a docker-compose file that I have all my stuff defined in. The box itself is given a static IP by the network (eero in this case). I run `docker-compose up -d`, and leave it to host my stuff.

Between a week and a day (it's inconsistent), the machine will just lose connectivity from the network. The current network setup is modem --> eero --> network switch --> server. The only way for me to reconnect to the server is to reboot it. Only then does the network come back online. I had this problem with Debian (happened on both 9 and 10) originally, but I changed my OS since a friend of mine runs Ubuntu without issue. I switched to Ubuntu Server (20), but have the same issue. Briefly, I did look at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36153 as a possible root cause, but adding the files suggested didn't seem to make a difference.

The next consideration was that maybe it was a hardware issue, so I switched from using my onboard ethernet to using a USB-C ethernet adapter. That seemed to work for 3 days, but then I had the same problem.

At this point, I'm lost as to what I can do to narrow down the problem. I've looked through `syslog`, but nothing seems to stand out to me there. I've checked the container logs, but all the containers are fine. On Debian I was using `Network Manager`, but on Ubuntu, I'm using `systemd-networkd`. Both experience this issue.

My Ubuntu version is `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-37-generic x86_64)`

My hardware info below in case that helps

```
H/W path              Device           Class          Description
=================================================================
                                       system         System Product Name (SKU)
/0                                     bus            PRIME X370-PRO
/0/0                                   memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/2c                                  memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/2c/0                                memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/2c/1                                memory         [empty]
/0/2c/2                                memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/2c/3                                memory         [empty]
/0/2e                                  memory         576KiB L1 cache
/0/2f                                  memory         3MiB L2 cache
/0/30                                  memory         16MiB L3 cache
/0/31                                  processor      AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor
/0/100                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
/0/100/0.2                             generic        Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
/0/100/1.3                             bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.3/0                           bus            X370 Series Chipset USB 3.1 xHCI Controller
/0/100/1.3/0/0        usb1             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.3/0/0/7                       generic        Belkin USB-C LAN
/0/100/1.3/0/1        usb2             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.3/0.1        scsi0            storage        X370 Series Chipset SATA Controller
/0/100/1.3/0.1/0      /dev/sda         disk           120GB SanDisk SDSSDA12
/0/100/1.3/0.1/0/1    /dev/sda1        volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1.3/0.1/0/2    /dev/sda2        volume         111GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1.3/0.1/1      /dev/sdb         disk           3TB Hitachi HUS72403
/0/100/1.3/0.1/2      /dev/sdc         disk           3TB Hitachi HUS72403
/0/100/1.3/0.1/3      /dev/sdd         disk           3TB Hitachi HUS72403
/0/100/1.3/0.1/4      /dev/sde         disk           3TB Hitachi HUS72403
/0/100/1.3/0.1/5      /dev/sdf         disk           3TB Hitachi HUS72403
/0/100/1.3/0.2                         bridge         X370 Series Chipset PCIe Upstream Port
/0/100/1.3/0.2/0                       bridge         300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
/0/100/1.3/0.2/2                       bridge         300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
/0/100/1.3/0.2/3                       bridge         300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
/0/100/1.3/0.2/4                       bridge         300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
/0/100/1.3/0.2/4/0                     bus            ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
/0/100/1.3/0.2/4/0/0  usb3             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.3/0.2/4/0/1  usb4             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.3/0.2/6                       bridge         300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
/0/100/1.3/0.2/6/0    enp7s0           network        I211 Gigabit Network Connection
/0/100/1.3/0.2/7                       bridge         300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
/0/100/3.2                             bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/3.2/0                           display        GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050]
/0/100/3.2/0.1                         multimedia     GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/7.1                             bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
/0/100/7.1/0                           generic        Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function
/0/100/7.1/0.2                         generic        Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
/0/100/7.1/0.3                         bus            Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) USB 3.0 Host Controller
/0/100/7.1/0.3/0      usb5             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/7.1/0.3/1      usb6             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1                             bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
/0/100/8.1/0                           generic        Zeppelin/Renoir PCIe Dummy Function
/0/100/8.1/0.2                         storage        FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/8.1/0.3                         multimedia     Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
/0/100/14                              bus            FCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.3                            bridge         FCH LPC Bridge
/0/101                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/102                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/103                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/104                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/105                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/106                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/107                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
/0/108                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
/0/109                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
/0/10a                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
/0/10b                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
/0/10c                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
/0/10d                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
/0/10e                                 bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
/0/1                                   system         PnP device PNP0c01
/0/2                                   system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/3                                   system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/4                                   communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/5                                   system         PnP device PNP0c02
/1                    br-10d6cc4b0f64  network        Ethernet interface
/2                    veth80c7cea      network        Ethernet interface
/3                    enx302303052de3  network        Ethernet interface
/4                    vethf4fd33e      network        Ethernet interface
/5                    vethab1d028      network        Ethernet interface
/6                    vethb9ac1e0      network        Ethernet interface
/7                    veth00d454b      network        Ethernet interface
/8                    docker0          network        Ethernet interface
```

Here is my docker-compose file too. My current docker version is `Docker version 19.03.11, build dd360c7`, and my docker-compose version is `docker-compose version 1.26.0, build d4451659`.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  plex:
    image: plexinc/pms-docker
    container_name: plex
    volumes:
      - /mnt/plex/config:/config
      - /mnt/plex/Movies:/data/movies
      - /mnt/plex/Shows:/data/tvshows
      - /mnt/plex/transcode:/data/transcode
    ports:
      - 32400:32400/tcp
      - 3005:3005/tcp
      - 8324:8324/tcp
      - 32469:32469/tcp
      - 1900:1900/udp
      - 32410:32410/udp
      - 32412:32412/udp
      - 32413:32413/udp
      - 32414:32414/udp
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - VERSION=latest
      - TZ=America/Los_Angeles
  homebridge:
    image: oznu/homebridge:latest
    container_name: homebridge
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Los_Angeles
      - PGID=1000
      - PUID=1000
      - HOMEBRIDGE_CONFIG_UI=1
      - HOMEBRIDGE_CONFIG_UI_PORT=8008
    volumes:
      - /mnt/homebridge:/homebridge
  nzbget:
    image: linuxserver/nzbget:latest
    container_name: nzbget
    volumes:
      - /mnt/nzbget/config:/config
      - /mnt/nzbget/downloads:/downloads
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Los_Angeles
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    ports:
      - 6789:6789
  sonarr:
    image: linuxserver/sonarr:latest
    container_name: sonarr
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - nzbget
    volumes:
      - /mnt/sonarr/config:/config
      - /mnt/nzbget/downloads:/downloads
      - /mnt/plex/Shows:/tv
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Los_Angeles
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    ports:
      - 8989:8989
  radarr:
    image: linuxserver/radarr:latest
    container_name: radarr
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - nzbget
    volumes:
      - /mnt/radarr/config:/config
      - /mnt/nzbget/downloads:/downloads
      - /mnt/plex/Movies:/movies
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Los_Angeles
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    ports:
      - 7878:7878
  tautulli:
    image: linuxserver/tautulli:latest
    container_name: tautulli
    depends_on:
      - plex
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Los_Angeles
      - PUID=1000
      - GUID=1000
    volumes:
      - /mnt/tautulli/config:/config
      - /mnt/tautulli/logs:/logs:ro
    ports:
      - 8181:8181
```

If I've missed anything, please let me know and I'm happy to provide more information.

EDIT:

I've also attempted to update the Realtek driver to the latest last night to see if that may be the cause of the issue because I found the following in `journalctl`

```
Jun 14 01:17:25 phoenix kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
Jun 14 01:17:25 phoenix kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
Jun 14 01:17:25 phoenix kernel: r8152 1-7:1.0 enx302303052de3: Tx status -108
Jun 14 01:17:25 phoenix kernel: r8152 1-7:1.0 enx302303052de3: Tx status -108
Jun 14 01:17:25 phoenix kernel: r8152 1-7:1.0 enx302303052de3: Tx status -108
Jun 14 01:17:25 phoenix kernel: r8152 1-7:1.0 enx302303052de3: Tx status -108
Jun 14 01:17:25 phoenix kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
Jun 14 01:17:25 phoenix kernel: r8152 1-7:1.0 enx302303052de3: Tx timeout
Jun 14 01:17:25 phoenix kernel: usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jun 14 01:17:25 phoenix kernel: r8152 1-7:1.0 enx302303052de3: Get ether addr fail
Jun 14 01:17:25 phoenix systemd-networkd[933]: enx302303052de3: Link DOWN
```

I did so following https://www.pcsuggest.com/install-rtl8153-driver-linux/. However, it seems things disconnected this morning so I can't say for sure if this helped or not.

EDIT 2:

It seems docker may be failing or restarting due to snap?

```
Jun 24 05:01:47 phoenix docker.dockerd[998]: failed to start containerd: timeout waiting for containerd to start
Jun 24 05:01:47 phoenix systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 24 05:01:47 phoenix systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 24 05:01:47 phoenix systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jun 24 05:01:47 phoenix systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
Jun 24 05:01:47 phoenix systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
```

After this I can clearly see an ip reassignment trigger which then caused my box to go offline

EDIT 3:

Here is a snippet from the iplog

```
[2020-07-05T00:24:28.507613] Deleted dev vetha537571 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:02 STALE
[2020-07-05T00:24:29.019491] 192.168.7.1 dev enp7s0 lladdr 14:22:db:9c:4d:ed PROBE
[2020-07-05T00:24:29.019674] 192.168.7.1 dev enp7s0 lladdr 14:22:db:9c:4d:ed REACHABLE
[2020-07-05T00:24:32.603688] 172.19.0.3 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:03 STALE
[2020-07-05T00:24:59.227481] 172.19.0.6 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:06 STALE
[2020-07-05T00:25:01.275258] 172.19.0.7 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:07 STALE
[2020-07-05T00:25:30.715499] 172.19.0.3 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:03 PROBE
[2020-07-05T00:25:30.715641] 172.19.0.3 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:03 REACHABLE
[2020-07-05T00:25:34.299181] 192.168.7.1 dev enp7s0 lladdr 14:22:db:9c:4d:ed STALE
[2020-07-05T00:25:38.139499] 192.168.7.50 dev enp7s0 lladdr 24:f5:a2:94:74:e9 STALE
[2020-07-05T00:25:38.139586] 192.168.7.55 dev enp7s0 lladdr 30:23:03:01:33:c5 STALE
[2020-07-05T00:25:39.931537] 192.168.7.1 dev enp7s0 lladdr 14:22:db:9c:4d:ed PROBE
[2020-07-05T00:25:39.931823] 192.168.7.1 dev enp7s0 lladdr 14:22:db:9c:4d:ed REACHABLE
[2020-07-05T00:25:47.099314] 192.168.7.50 dev enp7s0 lladdr 24:f5:a2:94:74:e9 PROBE
[2020-07-05T00:25:47.099401] 192.168.7.55 dev enp7s0 lladdr 30:23:03:01:33:c5 PROBE
[2020-07-05T00:25:47.101034] 192.168.7.50 dev enp7s0 lladdr 24:f5:a2:94:74:e9 REACHABLE
[2020-07-05T00:25:47.102485] 192.168.7.55 dev enp7s0 lladdr 30:23:03:01:33:c5 REACHABLE
[2020-07-05T00:25:57.595220] 172.19.0.6 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:06 PROBE
[2020-07-05T00:25:57.595308] 172.19.0.6 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:06 REACHABLE
[2020-07-05T00:25:58.363503] 172.19.0.7 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:07 PROBE
[2020-07-05T00:25:58.363730] 172.19.0.7 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:07 REACHABLE
[2020-07-05T00:26:00.667505] 172.19.0.3 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:03 STALE
[2020-07-05T00:26:12.955465] 192.168.7.1 dev enp7s0 lladdr 14:22:db:9c:4d:ed STALE
[2020-07-05T00:26:19.099249] 192.168.7.1 dev enp7s0 lladdr 14:22:db:9c:4d:ed PROBE
[2020-07-05T00:26:19.099393] 192.168.7.1 dev enp7s0 lladdr 14:22:db:9c:4d:ed REACHABLE
[2020-07-05T00:26:29.339502] 172.19.0.6 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:06 STALE
[2020-07-05T00:26:29.339583] 172.19.0.7 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:07 STALE
[2020-07-05T00:26:37.531222] 192.168.7.50 dev enp7s0 lladdr 24:f5:a2:94:74:e9 STALE
[2020-07-05T00:26:37.531304] 192.168.7.55 dev enp7s0 lladdr 30:23:03:01:33:c5 STALE
[2020-07-05T00:26:47.003597] 192.168.7.55 dev enp7s0 lladdr 30:23:03:01:33:c5 PROBE
[2020-07-05T00:26:47.003678] 192.168.7.50 dev enp7s0 lladdr 24:f5:a2:94:74:e9 PROBE
[2020-07-05T00:26:47.005742] 192.168.7.55 dev enp7s0 lladdr 30:23:03:01:33:c5 REACHABLE
[2020-07-05T00:26:47.007351] 192.168.7.50 dev enp7s0 lladdr 24:f5:a2:94:74:e9 REACHABLE
[2020-07-05T00:27:00.827525] 172.19.0.3 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:03 PROBE
[2020-07-05T00:27:00.827816] 172.19.0.3 dev br-c5ca2723d156 lladdr 02:42:ac:13:00:03 REACHABLE
[2020-07-05T00:27:12.859480] 192.168.7.1 dev enp7s0 lladdr 14:22:db:9c:4d:ed STALE
[2020-07-05T00:27:19.003172] 192.168.7.1 dev enp7s0 lladdr 14:22:db:9c:4d:ed PROBE
```

Comment: No, the server IP is in the `192.168.7.0`-`192.168.7.255` range. However, the docker IP is `172.17.0.1` and the docker bridge IP is `172.18.0.1`

Comment: Oh didn't see the issue about USB. No way to use an other ethernet device, preferably not on USB?

Comment: I added it right after answering you, sorry. This is kind of an ongoing thing so I keep trying to add more information. I was experiencing the same issue with onboard ethernet, hence I switched to a USB ethernet adapter to try and rule out hardware. The issue happens with both onboard and USB :/

Comment: Anyway, you could revert to onboard and check the message. I understand you'd also get a link down, but maybe not a card failure. The common point could be the remote side (eg: a switch)

Comment: I’ll give that a go. I just had another disconnect this morning. I did find a number of errors in the journal about this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173. I’ve updated my grub per the bug and rebooted. Going to try hardwired next.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try hardwired yet, but I noticed this after a recent failure that docker may be getting restarted by snapd, and then that causes an address reassignment on devices? See the edit above

Comment: Doesn't seem relevant to the problem. Anyway without a clear reproducer, this question is just difficult to answer. Once you can reproduce the problem and describe how it happens, then an answer becomes easier.

Comment: I have found that running `docker-compose pull` routinely seems to crash the network driver while I'm ssh'ed.

Comment: If crash means "network changed", you'll have to record what network change happened. You should keep running (for example in a screen command or whatever that doesn't require to be connected) this command for further analysis: `ip -ts monitor > /path/to/some/iplog.txt`. It logs a lot of things, you can grep it later. Especially the `Deleted` entries. Your 1st comment told you don't have any network clash with docker's networks, so I'd be surprised.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've switched back to onboard ethernet, and also set the IP to be static on the device (in addition to already having it set by the router). I've kicked off the command you provided by running `nohup ip -ts monitor > iplog.txt &` so it is backgrounded after I leave my `ssh` session. I will report back what I find.

Comment: So I had the longest up time (almost a week), but then it collapsed again. There is one line that keeps showing up with `Deleted`. I've added a snippet to the first comment

Comment: the only Deleted entry I see in your post is a stale ARP cache entry: it's not related and harmless (and usual in normal operations). Sorry I don't have any idea left about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This took me some more digging to find out. But eventually I had my computer running with it plugged into my monitor and I saw a CPU lockup the next time I lost network connectivity.

Some quick searching seems to point to the possibility it is a power state problem with Ryzen CPUs https://askubuntu.com/a/1259021

Following that answer, I followed this guide to disable the C6 power state https://forum.manjaro.org/t/fix-ryzen-lockups-related-to-low-system-usage/39723

I'm verging on 3 days of uptime without any issue. Currently on wifi, but intend to switch the machine back to wired. I will update in a month to see how the uptime has been since then. Hopefully this helps the next person who experiences a similar issue.

EDIT 2022: original link went dead, here is the archive.org link https://web.archive.org/web/20200417190251/https://forum.manjaro.org/t/fix-ryzen-lockups-related-to-low-system-usage/39723

Comment: Did this fix the issue for you? Is your system running stable now? I am experiencing the same symptoms but only with an Intel CPU instead.

Comment: Yep, this solved my issue. I’ve had zero issues since I did this.

Comment: Downvoting. You're supposed to provide an answer, not link to one, because links go dead, as this one has.

Comment: @JohnSmith sorry about that! Here’s the archive.org version of the link above. https://web.archive.org/web/20200417190251/https://forum.manjaro.org/t/fix-ryzen-lockups-related-to-low-system-usage/39723